# How to add & remove active state in bootstrap btn

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function openclass(className) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("standard");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(className).style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="page-header">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active" aria-pressed="true" onclick="openclass('viewclass')">View Class</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" aria-pressed="true" onclick="openclass('addclass')">Add Class</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="openclass('addsection')">Add Section</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="openclass('assignteacher')">Assign Teacher</button>
</div>

<div id="viewclass" class="standard">
  <h1>View Class</h1>

</div>

<div id="addclass" class="standard" style="display:none">
  <h2>Add Class</h2>
</div>

<div id="addsection" class="standard" style="display:none">
  <h2>add section</h2>
</div>

<div id="assignteacher" class="standard" style="display:none">
  <h2>assign teacher</h2>
</div>
```

With first button already active, I want to make every other button active on click and and remove older active, I know it can be done through js but really can't seem to figure it out

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What do you mean by "active on click"?

Comment: By active on click i mean i want add class="active"

Comment: and remove the previous active

Comment: check `classList.add`, `classList.remove`, `classList.toggle` methods

Comment: @capchuck what do you mean ?, can you please explain

Comment: @AazimKhaki take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/how-can-i-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript/196038#196038

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change an element's class with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/how-can-i-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Comment: don't think so, still confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add the clickedbutton inside the `onclick` arguments. You can do that by using the `this` keyword. So `onclick=openClass(this, 'className')`

And then, on click, remove all the ' active classes ' and add the `active` class to the `clickedButton`

```js
function openclass(clickedBtn, className) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("standard");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(`${className}`).style.display = "block";
  // add remove active class
  document.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach(btn => btn.classList.contains('active') && btn.classList.remove('active'))
    clickedBtn.classList.add('active')

}
```

```css
.btn.active {
    background:Red;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-header">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active" aria-pressed="true" onclick="openclass(this,'viewclass')">View Class</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" aria-pressed="true" onclick="openclass(this, 'addclass')">Add Class</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="openclass(this,'addsection')">Add Section</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="openclass(this,'assignteacher')">Assign Teacher</button>
 </div>

 <div id="viewclass" class="standard">
   <h1>View Class</h1>

 </div>

 <div id="addclass" class="standard" style="display:none">
   <h2>Add Class</h2>
 </div>

 <div id="addsection" class="standard" style="display:none">
   <h2>add section</h2>
 </div>

 <div id="assignteacher" class="standard" style="display:none">
   <h2>assign teacher</h2>
 </div>
```